# Alternative to getting ServerVariables from Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, application-start

I have my webservice running on IIS in Integrated mode. In this mode, `HttpContext.Request` throws exception, when is called from `Application_Start` method.

```
// app is HttpApplication
var serverName = app.Context.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"];
```

The above statement would throw System.Web.HttpException: Request is not available in this context

Is there somewhere else, where I can retrieve ServerVariables from, within `Application_Start`?

Comment: App start may be called when there isn't a request, that's why you don't have access to a request object.

Comment: Well documented by Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis#16-it-is-not-possible-to-access-the-request-through-the-httpcontextcurrent-property-in-applicationstart-in-globalasax

Comment: Why are you trying to get SERVER_NAME when the application starts?  AFAIK SERVER_NAME reflects the name in the request URL without the port number.  You could potentially have multiple host names coming into one site, so it would be good to explain what you are looking to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HostingEnvironment`

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment
```

It has a lot of properties you can use